# Electric sockets & plugs - role of the live wire

Tags: electric-circuits

I have read this:

> The live wire carries the alternating potential difference from the supply. The neutral wire
> completes the circuit. The earth wire is a safety wire to stop the appliance becoming live.

My question is related to this phrase, "The live wire carries the alternating potential difference from the supply."

It seems wrong. How can a wire ***carry*** a potential difference? Surely wires carry current not pd?

Comment: Suppose you have a 9 volt battery. Do you think there is any current flowing at the battery terminals when it is not connected to anything? Do you think the 9 volts potential difference only appears when there *is* a current flowing? If you think that, how does the battery "know" when you connect it to something and it should start producing the potential difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems wrong. How can a wire carry a potential difference? Surely
> wires carry current not pd?

What they are referring to is that the live, or more properly called ungrounded, circuit conductor carries the potential difference to the neutral, or more properly called the grounded circuit conductor, which is intended to be kept at ground or zero potential along with the safety wire, or more properly called the equipment grounding conductor.

See the diagram below for a US residential 120/240 volt rms system, showing a 120 outlet, and the associated wave form. The neutral and grounding circuit conductor is at (or near) zero potential. The live conductor potential varies sinusoidally about ground potential.

> What does it mean to "carry potential difference" though? Carrying
> current makes sense - the wire facilitates the flow of electrons - but
> how pd is "carried" is not too obvious to me?

I agree it's a poor term to use, and is not obvious. In any event, it is only on the live (ungrounded) conductor where the potential varies sinusoidally with respect to the neutral which is at zero potential. In my opinion, that's the only thing I believe they meant.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: What does it mean to "carry potential difference" though? Carrying current makes sense - the wire facilitates the flow of electrons - but how pd is "carried" is not too obvious to me?

Comment: I agree it's a poor term to use, and is not obvious.  In any event, it is only on the live (ungrounded) conductor where the potential varies sinusoidally with respect to the neutral. IMO that't the only thing I believe they  meant.